# I have a existing laravel Web App we wrapped in an android application, and need to save user logins

Tags: java, android, laravel

We have an existing web application we developed and needed to port over to an android application for people in the field. So we have a shell of an android application that just points to the URL and displays it. I want to save the user credentials so if they timeout/close application and re-click the application it will auto log them in always after the first time.

I am looking at `SharedPrefrences` as other threads here have done, but not sure how to capture the creds from the web input elements. Can I use SharedPrefrences to accomplish this still? If so how do I target that input?

Answer (score 1):

You do NOT save the user credentials.  Ever.  Saving them means they can be read by malware.  And no, encryption can't help as the encryption key would need to be in your app or on your filesystem.

Instead, you have your login API return a token.  This token will be sent back to the server with every request (either as a parameter or a cookie).  The server will then use this token to look up the user id on the server and figure out who it is.  That token can be saved to SharedPreferences.  (This is the simplest version, there are more advanced things you can do as well, but this is sufficient).

Why is this safer than storing the password?  Because passwords can and frequently are shared between multiple apps, so losing a password can compromise multiple accounts.

BTW, this is also how webapps work.  They don't send the username/password with every request, when they login a cookie is saved with a token, and its sent back with every future request.